# Detect if two files are hard linked in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, hardlink

I know I can use the command

```
fsutil hardlink <new_file> <existing file>
```

[To create a hard link](http://jameser.blogspot.com/2006/08/tip-37-creating-ntfs-hard-links-in.html) from the command prompt.

My question is: is there a command line tool that will allow me to see whether two files are hard linked, similar to `ls -i` in unix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the HLScan tool from MS.

"Displays hard links on an NTFS volume or in specified files or directories of the volume."

It's part of the Windows resource kit(s).

Here's [a direct link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=289adee4-abb3-4e18-ab07-c77db8654979&displaylang=en) to download the Windows 2000 version of JUST that utility (it works on XP).

You can probably dig up the XP or 2003 specific Resource kits by searching MS's download site; those may have a newer version of the utility in them.

HTH.

Comment: nice tool, thanks. although it doesn't show the destination, only that the file is hard-linked and the count

Answer (score 3):

fsutil will show them without a download (and it will work on Windows 7)

```
fsutil hardlink list <filename>
```

Comment: FYI, on WinXP `list` command is not supported (only `create`)